# c++ program with .NET compression

Tags: .net, compression, c++-cli

Is there any way to use .NET GZipStream class from a C++ code? I tried setting up my visual studio project so it supports CLR, but VS didin't let me use System.IO.Compression namespace.

```
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::IO::Compression;  // System::IO does not have member "Compression"


void compressFile(System::String^ str) {

    FileStream^ fs = File::OpenWrite(str);

    {
             //Creating a gZipStream from a FileStream here and compressing
             //Disposing from a gZipStream
    }

    fs->Dispose();

}


int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What error did it give?

Comment: Did you add a reference to System.IO.Compression.dll?

Comment: I tried to add reference to it, but "Assemblies" list doesn't seem to have such assembly.

Comment: Actually it should be `System` assembly.

Comment: System assembly is in use, because I can use System::String.

Comment: Browse to `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IO.Compression\{version}\`

Comment: @MokonaModoki `System::String` is in `mscorlib`, not `System`.